# How to use query value in sub-query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have following query. Basically I am finding email id of users under specific manager

```
SELECT Users.Email AS Email, Users.ManagerId AS ManagerId,
[AssignedUser] = (SELECT Users.UserName FROM Users WHERE Users.Id = Users.ManagerId)
FROM Users
WHERE Users.ManagerId = 'someid'
```

I am getting Email and ManagerId values perfectly fine, but in AssignedUser I am getting NULL values..  check below screenshot.

[image]

Comment: SQL Server is not the same as SQLite - please correct your tags.

Comment: As per the question guide, please do not post images of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text.

Comment: You've used the same alias i.e. no alias for your users table in the sub-query and in the parent query - which table do you think SQL Server is going to use for `Users.Id = Users.ManagerId`? Its always going to resolve that to the *nearest* matching table. Add actual aliases and make them different so you can differentiate between your two instances of the same table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try like this one.

```
SELECT t.Email AS Email,
      (SELECT s.Email FROM Users s WHERE s.Id = t.ManagerId) as some_col
FROM Users t WHERE t.ManagerId = 'someid'
```

Comment: A good answer should also explain itself in addition to providing a working solution.